# Spring data neo4j incoming relationship STRING is not iterable

Tags: spring, relationship, spring-data-neo4j

I have a graph database with relationship ACTED_IN between nodes Person and Prod (movies) pointing to Prod. I am using spring boot data neo4j for getting data from cloud basedd database to my application. I can't  reflect this ACTED_IN relation in my code in a way to have relationship properties like "characters" beeing a list of String stating who the Person played in the movie. This is my best attempt so far and the Error I am getting:

Example of a ACTED_IN query result in Neo4j cloud:

```
*(:Person {primaryProfession: ["actress"], birthYear: 1929, deathYear: 2003, name: "Queta Claver", nconst: "nm0165424"})-[:ACTED_IN {characters: "["Mimi"]", order: "1"}]->(:Prod {runtimeMinutes: 85, titleType: ["movie"], genres: ["Comedy", "Musical"], originalTitle: "La bella Mimí", tconst: "tt0054675", startYear: 1961, title: "Beautiful Mimi"})*
```

Person class:

```
@Node
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long identity;
    private int birthYear;
    private int deathYear;
    private String name;
    private String[] primaryProfession;

    public int getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }

    public int getDeathYear() {
        return deathYear;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String[] getPrimaryProfession() {
        return primaryProfession;
    }
}
```

Prod class:

```
@Node
public class Prod {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long identity;
    private String[] genres;
    private String originalTitle;
    private String title;
    private String[] titleType;
    private int runtimeMinutes;
    private int startYear;
    @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private List<ActedIn> actors;

    private Prod() {
        // Empty constructor required as of Neo4j API 2.0.5
    };
    public Long getIdentity(){
        return identity;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public String getOriginalTitle(){
        return originalTitle;
    }
    public String[] getGenres() {
        return genres;
    }
    public String[] getTitleType() {
        return titleType;
    }
    public int getRuntimeMinutes() {
        return runtimeMinutes;
    }
    public int getStartYear() {
        return startYear;
    }
    public List<ActedIn> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }
}
```

Class that should reflect the relationship:

```
@RelationshipProperties
public final class ActedIn {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long identity;
    @TargetNode
    private Person person;
    private Prod prod;
    @Property("characters")
    private List<String> characters;
    @Property("order")
    private String order;

    public ActedIn(Person person, List<String> characters, String order) {
        this.person = person;
        this.characters = characters;
        this.order = order;
    }
    public Long getIdentity() {
        return identity;
    }
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public List<String> getCharacters() {
        return characters;
    }
    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
    public Prod getProd() {
        return prod;
    }
}
```

Endpoint I use to get prod details:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/movie/{identity}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Prod getMovieById(@PathVariable Long identity) {
        Prod prod = prodDao.findProdByIdentity(identity);
        return prod;
    }
```

and the first few lines of the Error I am getting from neo4j driver:

```
Error mapping Record<{prod: {Prod_ACTED_IN_Person: [{__internalNeo4jId__: 8203, birthYear: 1931, deathYear: NULL, primaryProfession: ["actress"], __elementId__: "8203", name: "Carroll Baker", Prod__relationship__Person: relationship<19>, __nodeLabels__: ["Person"]}], runtimeMinutes: 113, __internalNeo4jId__: 7222, titleType: ["movie"], genres: ["Drama", "Romance", "War"], originalTitle: "Bridge to the Sun", __elementId__: "7222", startYear: 1961, title: "Bridge to the Sun", __nodeLabels__: ["Prod"]}}>
2023-06-22T21:29:49.767+02:00 ERROR 6416 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Error mapping Record<{prod: {Prod_ACTED_IN_Person: [{__internalNeo4jId__: 8203, birthYear: 1931, deathYear: NULL, primaryProfession: ["actress"], __elementId__: "8203", name: "Carroll Baker", Prod__relationship__Person: relationship<19>, __nodeLabels__: ["Person"]}], runtimeMinutes: 113, __internalNeo4jId__: 7222, titleType: ["movie"], genres: ["Drama", "Romance", "War"], originalTitle: "Bridge to the Sun", __elementId__: "7222", startYear: 1961, title: "Bridge to the Sun", __nodeLabels__: ["Prod"]}}>] with root cause
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.value.NotMultiValued: STRING is not iterable
```

If I delete *actors* from Prod, endpoint is returning the Prod I asked for from the database with no issues.